# How to fetch data from given format on datatable?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to write logic to display data in datatable. Below is the table I need to display.

[image]

There will be only 5 columns Day1 to Day5.
In rows, if dayName='DAY 1' then data present in weekDay arrayList needs to be fetch like Music Theme(which is value to theme key in weekDay arrayList). 10 mins is themeTime and singing practice is title and so on.

Below is format of data -

```
[
    {
        "id": "7658dc9e-5720-4544-8780-761e1993a8a3",
        "folderMapID": "d56eb3ff-dc9f-477e-82b2-ffc29a12b9f1",
        "themeName": "test",
        "classTime": 45,
        "dayName": "DAY 2",
        "isActive": true,
        "weekDay": [
            {
                "id": "2cebd6c7-339d-4d99-a199-b1c145211272",
                "position": 1,
                "theme": "QA Theme One",
                "themeTime": 14,
                "title": "test title",
                "isActive": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "8f638849-6e54-4949-b404-300aa2c8a0c0",
        "folderMapID": "d56eb3ff-dc9f-477e-82b2-ffc29a12b9f1",
        "themeName": "Butterfly Theme",
        "classTime": 60,
        "dayName": "DAY 1",
        "isActive": true,
        "weekDay": [
            {
                "id": "3796dac9-18b0-4dd4-912f-8aeeede84e6b",
                "position": 1,
                "theme": "Music Theme",
                "themeTime": 10,
                "title": "singing practice",
                "isActive": true
            },
            {
                "id": "57b8f608-d2ad-4f7b-807b-db75aa0d10a9",
                "position": 2,
                "theme": "Dance Theme",
                "themeTime": 15,
                "title": "learn dance steps",
                "isActive": true
            },
            {
                "id": "d395b047-2847-474a-a553-afbd93782092",
                "position": 3,
                "theme": "QA Theme One",
                "themeTime": 20,
                "title": "QA testing",
                "isActive": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

HTML template -

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="weekScheduleList" disable-pagination
    hide-default-footer>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        <v-card-subtitle class="d-flex justify-center">No Data Available</v-card-subtitle>
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

```
 export default {
    data () {
      return {
        weekScheduleList: [],
        theme: '',
        headers: [
          { text: 'DAY 1', value: 'theme', align: 'center', sortable: true },
          { text: 'DAY 2', value: '0', align: 'center', sortable: true },
          { text: 'DAY 3', value: '0', align: 'center', sortable: true },
          { text: 'DAY 4', value: '0', align: 'center', sortable: true },
          { text: 'DAY 5', value: '0', align: 'center', sortable: true }
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getWeekScheduleList: async function () {
        try {
          this.isLoading = true
          let res = await http.get(`${CONSTANTS.API_URL}/api/get-week/${this.folderId}`)

          const days = res.data
        const newData = []

        days.forEach(day => {
          const row = {
            day: day.dayName
          }

          day.weekDay.forEach(weekDay => {
            row[weekDay.theme] = `${weekDay.theme} - ${weekDay.themeTime} mins - ${weekDay.title}`
          })

          newData.push(row)
        })

        this.weekScheduleList = newData

        console.log('this.weekScheduleList :', this.weekScheduleList) 

        } catch (e) {
          const errorMessage = (e && e.response && e.response.data.message) || e.message
          this.errMsg(errorMessage)
        } 
      },
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per looking at your tabular UI, you need to convert your API data in the below format where each row would have all 5 days' data.

```
[
  {
   // Day 1,
   // Day 2,
   // Day 3,
   // Day 4,
   // Day 5
  },
  {
   // Day 1,
   // Day 2,
   // Day 3,
   // Day 4,
   // Day 5
  }
]
```

Try the below logic in your `getWeekScheduleList` function. I added the respective comments to explain the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="weekScheduleList"
        disable-pagination
        hide-default-footer
        >
      </v-data-table>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),

        data() {
          return {
            weekScheduleList: [],
            theme: "",
            headers: [{
                text: "DAY 1",
                value: "DAY 1",
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true
              },
              {
                text: "DAY 2",
                value: "DAY 2",
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true
              },
              {
                text: "DAY 3",
                value: "DAY 3",
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true
              },
              {
                text: "DAY 4",
                value: "DAY 4",
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true
              },
              {
                text: "DAY 5",
                value: "DAY 5",
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true
              },
            ],
            api_data: [{
                id: "7658dc9e-5720-4544-8780-761e1993a8a3",
                folderMapID: "d56eb3ff-dc9f-477e-82b2-ffc29a12b9f1",
                themeName: "test",
                classTime: 45,
                dayName: "DAY 2",
                isActive: true,
                weekDay: [{
                  id: "2cebd6c7-339d-4d99-a199-b1c145211272",
                  position: 1,
                  theme: "QA Theme One",
                  themeTime: 14,
                  title: "test title",
                  isActive: true,
                }, ],
              },
              {
                id: "8f638849-6e54-4949-b404-300aa2c8a0c0",
                folderMapID: "d56eb3ff-dc9f-477e-82b2-ffc29a12b9f1",
                themeName: "Butterfly Theme",
                classTime: 60,
                dayName: "DAY 1",
                isActive: true,
                weekDay: [{
                    id: "3796dac9-18b0-4dd4-912f-8aeeede84e6b",
                    position: 1,
                    theme: "Music Theme",
                    themeTime: 10,
                    title: "singing practice",
                    isActive: true,
                  },
                  {
                    id: "57b8f608-d2ad-4f7b-807b-db75aa0d10a9",
                    position: 2,
                    theme: "Dance Theme",
                    themeTime: 15,
                    title: "learn dance steps",
                    isActive: true,
                  },
                  {
                    id: "d395b047-2847-474a-a553-afbd93782092",
                    position: 3,
                    theme: "QA Theme One",
                    themeTime: 20,
                    title: "QA testing",
                    isActive: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          };
        },
        mounted() {
          this.getWeekScheduleList();
        },
        methods: {
          getWeekScheduleList: async function() {
            try {
              var api_data = this.api_data;
              var total_days = 5;
              // Sort the api data by day's name first
              api_data.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.dayName.localeCompare(b.dayName);
              });
              // Find the item which has maximum weedays
              let max_weekday_item = this.api_data.find((item) =>
                Math.max(item.weekDay.length)
              );
              // Outer loop for row - API data
              for (
                let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < max_weekday_item.weekDay.length; rowIndex++
              ) {
                const row = {};
                // Inner loop for column
                for (let colIndex = 1; colIndex <= total_days; colIndex++) {
                  // Find the item of respective day number
                  let day_item = this.api_data.find((item) => {
                    return item.dayName === `DAY ${colIndex}`;
                  });
                  /**
                   * If found then assign like this-
                   * row['DAY 1'] = Day 1's weekday data
                   * row['DAY 2'] = Day 2's weekday data
                   */

                  if (day_item) {
                    row[`DAY ${colIndex}`] = day_item.weekDay[rowIndex] ?
                      `${day_item.weekDay[rowIndex].theme} - ${day_item.weekDay[rowIndex].themeTime} mins - ${day_item.weekDay[rowIndex].title}` :
                      "";
                  }
                  // Else leave it empty
                  else {
                    row[`DAY ${colIndex}`] = "";
                  }
                }
                // Push this row's data in the array
                this.weekScheduleList.push(row);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              console.error(e);
            }
          },
        },
       })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If we add one more row to day1 then that data is not getting reflected.